# Inline-block causing troubles on IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, css

A few months ago, I made a site for a small company. They were very pleased about it, and so on. Now, I will do a small ecommerce for the same company, and integrate it to the site base. But, I was looking it with ie7, and noticed something terrible. The navbar, isn't displaying correctly. The links, normally listed on horizontal line, are on vertical line. How to fix this, this is urgent?

Here's the CSS of the nav:

```css
.nav-ul  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -14px;
    top: 120px;
    background: #000;
    height: 31px;
    z-index:  2;
    width: 104%;
    background-image: nappulat/tyhja.png;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 128px;
    height: 31px;
}

.nav-ul li:hover {
    background-color: #b2080b;
}

.nav-ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana,  Geneva,  sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 128px;
    height: 31px;
}
```

I know the conditional comments, would they give me an answer?

Comment: IE 7 doesn;t support inline-block. You probably need to float your li's instead

Comment: I've heard that some people have been able to fix this. And float is not an option, because the size differences.

Comment: I usually use display inline for inline block elements for IE 7, can you create a fiddle so we can fiddle around with it

Comment: yea just set .nav-ul li to display inline for IE 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE7 (and IE6) has some serious bugs with `inline-block`.

The main bug is that it only works at all for elements that have a default `display` style of `inline`.

`<li>` tags have a default style of `list-item`, and therefore `display:inline-block;` won't work for them in IE7.

There are two solutions:

1. Add a `<span>` or similar inline tag inside the `<li>` (or instead of your `<li>`) and style that as `inline-block` instead. This may or may not have the desired effect for you, depending on what you're trying to achieve.
2. Use an IE CSS hack. You can make IE7 do what you want if you set `display:inline;` and `zoom:1;`. This combination will work in IE6 and IE7 in the way `inline-block` is supposed to work. You'll need to work out a way to make this only happen in IE6/7, though, because obviously you'll want it to use `inline-block` in other browsers. There are various CSS hacks that can target these browsers, or you could use conditional comments. Either way, it's messy, but the only real solution if you want to support IE7.

(which brings up the third option, of dropping support for IE7 in your site...)

Answer (score 0):

Not fully supported in IE 7 according to http://caniuse.com/inline-block  (only for elements that are inline by default).  It mentions alternatives here ... http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Conditional comments would help you if you have a version that looks ok in IE7 and have something else that looks better in newer browsers, so you would use different code for different browser versions

Comment: The site looks perfect on ie7, if you don't count the navigation. So I'd rather not use another stylesheet if there's another option...

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display: inline;
```

Should work. Make sure you have a valid DOCTYPE set. You can remove "zoom:1" if there is something else that triggers [hasLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).